# how to use -> operand in julia to apply filter based on two index?

Tags: julia

I have a list of tuples like `A = [(3, 4, 5, "s2", "s2") , (2, 4, 5, "s1", "s2"), (3, 4, 6, "s2", "s2"),(1, 4, 6, "s2", "s3"),(1, 3, 6, "s3", "s3"),....]`

I want to filter out all tuples that their forth and fifth elements are the same, and group them baes on the  forth elements.
And also find all tuples that their forth and fifth are not the same, and again group them based on the forth elements.

What I, looking for is like the following. This is for when fifth and forth are the same:

```
"s1" │ []
"s2" │ [(3, 4, 5, "s2", "s2"), (3, 4, 6, "s2", "s2")]
"s3" │ [(1, 3, 6, "s3", "s3")]
```

How to achieve this via Julia?

Answer (score 2):

One way might be:

```
foldl((r,e)->(e[4]==e[5] && push!(r[e[4]],e); r),A ;
  init=Dict(k=>eltype(A)[] for k in 
    Base.Fix2(nth,4).(A) |> unique |> sort))
```

Giving the following output:

```
julia> A = [(3, 4, 5, "s2", "s2") , (2, 4, 5, "s1", "s2"), (3, 4, 6, "s2", "s2"),(1, 4, 6, "s2", "s3"),(1, 3, 6, "s3", "s3")];

julia> foldl((r,e)->(e[4]==e[5] && push!(r[e[4]],e); r),A ;init=Dict(k=>eltype(A)[] for k in Base.Fix2(nth,4).(A) |> unique |> sort))
Dict{String, Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64, Int64, String, String}}} with 3 entries:
  "s1" => []
  "s2" => [(3, 4, 5, "s2", "s2"), (3, 4, 6, "s2", "s2")]
  "s3" => [(1, 3, 6, "s3", "s3")]
```

A few Julia base features are used:

- `foldl` with `init` parameter.
- `Base.Fix2` to create a partially computed `nth`.
- `&&` short-circuit to implement `if` logic.
- `|>` pipe operator.
- Generator (similar to comprehension) for Dict initialization.

Comment: Although the output order of the Dict is `s1`, `s2`, `s3`, it is not an OrderedCollection. Replacing the Dict with an OrderedDict would ensure this order.